# Which algorithm is robust to noisy data? (Decision Tree, K-Mean clustering, HMM)

Tags: unsupervised-learning

I assume HMM will be the most robust to noisy data since it derives a generative model compared to Decision Tree and K-Mean?

Between decision tree and K-mean, which methods is robust to noisy data? I found K-mean may not work well with outliers.

However, with my data (prior knowledge of number of clusters and expected attribute values), K-Mean seems to generate closer outcomes than DT.
Can anyone provide any possible reason about this situation?